# Get a signal once a subprocess ends

Tags: python, pyqt4, popen

I am using the subprocess.Popen function to run a command line. Without having to use Popen.wait(), I want to check the subprocess after it has finished using Popen.poll(). Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
import subprocess
job = subprocess.Popen('command line', shell = True)
print(job.poll())
```

As it is, I get job.poll() printed before the subprocess starts. I want it to wait until it ends. I don't want to use wait because the rest of the user interface becomes unusable until the process ends. This is in PyQt4.

Comment: Can you please clarify - *the rest of the user interface becomes unusable until the process ends.* ?

Comment: Yes. I want my program to be able to run this command line in the background and let the user know when it has finished. However, I wanna be able to keep working on the program while the subprocess is going on. Using the wait function "blocks/freezes" the program and I cannot keep working on it until the subprocess ends. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you are looking for interreupts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background thread with QThread in PyQt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 0):

As [Python - wait on a condition without high cpu usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010144/python-wait-on-a-condition-without-high-cpu-usage) says, there are only two ways in existence to wait for something: polling or setting up/using a notification system.

If it's UI - didn't you forget about one notification system you always have - the message queue?

Besides, you can always (and, if it's UI, *should always*) perform any time-consuming tasks in worker threads. If which case, you are just fine with a synchronous call.

Comment: I am not familiar with Python well and I am learning as I work on making my program. I would really appreciate it if you could explain what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: For UI, a worker thread is actually the standard solution. You didn't tell anything about which UI library/related techs you use, so I cannot be any more specific as of now.

Comment: I am using PyQt4 to build the UI